# Can a pregnant woman go through the Sotah process?

Tags: halacha, pregnancy-birth, sotah

A woman is 3 months pregnant from her husband. He now warns her not to seclude with Ploni. She does seclude and have carnal relations with Ploni.

If she is treated as a Sotah, the embryo will be lost as well as the woman.

So my question is whether a pregnant woman can go through the Sotah process.

Comment: "If his own pregnant or nursing wife becomes a sota, then despite the concern that the bitter water may harm the fetus, she either drinks the bitter water or does not collect payment of her marriage contract" -Sotah 26a:4 ??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A pregnant women can be a Sotah but only if she is pregnant to her own husbands child.

The Gemorah  Sotah 26A says

מְעוּבֶּרֶת חֲבֵירוֹ וּמֵינֶקֶת חֲבֵירוֹ לֹא שׁוֹתוֹת

*A woman who was pregnant with the child of another man at the time of her marriage and a woman who was nursing the child of another man at the time of her marriage does not drink the Sotah waters*

The Gemorah continues on to say explicitly that she would go through the process if she were pregnant with his child.

In general if a women does a crime that carries the death penalty we do not wait for her to give birth before carrying it out.

Comment: And Rambam rules this way in Hilchot Sotah 2:7